# append draggable to container jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui

i ran into a little problem every time select an image from my gallery the image is displayed into a container i can resize and drag the image within the container my problem is that the image hides when i drag the image beyond the container what i  want is for the image to stop right on the container i dont want it to hide. how can  make this possible? here is what i have i dont have a working draggable beacause that will require alot of coding im just going to post the script and some CSS and HTML

```js
  $('img').on('click', function() {
    $('#fotos').append('<div class="imgdrag"><img class="modal-content" src="' + $(this).attr('src') + '"/></div>');
    $('.imgdrag').draggable({appendTo: $(".container5")});
    $('#fotos').droppable();
    $('.modal-content').resizable();

    $(".download").attr("href", $(this).attr('src'));
    $(".download").show();
  });
```

```css
.container5 {
  background-color: transparent;
  width: 220px;
  height: 320px;
  margin: auto;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  border: 1px solid red;
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div id="boxes" class="container5" style="float:center;">
<div id="fotos" class="bananas"><img class="modal-content" id="imgdisplay" /></div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the containment option for resizeable you can enter a selector that the resizeable will stay within.
You could even use the parent string so it stays in the parent element

for example

```
 $('.modal-content').resizable({
       containment: "parent"
 });
```

Comment: Have a look at the jsfiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/mgoo/x06dg7ec/) for a full example of it working. you can also have a look at the documentation [here](http://api.jqueryui.com/resizable/#option-containment)